# How i can get weekend date by giving specific date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to get weekend date of `17-03-2021`

Currently in am getting weekend date of current week i want to get by specific date.

```
Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('d-m-Y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('d-m-Y')` is doing what you want, just not with a specific date, then parse the date you want to base this from:

`Carbon::parse('17-03-2021')->endOfWeek()->format('d-m-Y')`

Also consider `->nextWeekendDay()` and `->previousWeekendDay()` as ways to access the weekend.